# Dynamic find and replace in Word files with DocuSign

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document that I am using as the basis for a DocuSign template.

There are various placeholders left in this document, such as `[NAME]`, which are meant to be replaced with the signatory's data at the time of signing:

[image: Initial format]

I would like DocuSign to do the following:

1. Find "[NAME]"
2. Replace it with the recipient's name
3. Do the replacement in such a way that the text to the right (i.e. starting with `the "Investor"`) is pushed further to the right and down, just like if I had modified the text in Word manually

Basically, I would like the result to be this:

[image: End result]

I know that these dynamic fills are typically done via dotted placeholders (".........") but I cannot modify the contents of the document, so I'm stuck with this format.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe with [AutoPlace](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience)?

Comment: Docusign [placeholders](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/document-generation/) are written with curly brackets. You say that the template is unchangeable?

Comment: Unchangeable, yes, but I would still like to know if this is doable (for other signatures). I looked at the placeholders link you shared - looks like it's only available in the API?